# Google Script - Stop Duplicate Calendar Events

Tags: google-apps-script

I am currently rolling out a delivery system, the first step of this is to get a google sheet integrating with google calendar.

I have managed to get this working but the issue is, I can't figure out a way to get the calendar to check if the ID Number (In spreadsheet as D.O#) already exists to not create another event for this. The reason I would have multiple lines with the same ID number is because I require a seperate line for each item that is being delivered even if its the same job in order to be able to upload it to the delivery side of things.  I had it set to not create multiple events if the eventID column was populated but this doesn't seem to be working correctly either. Any help is appreciated!!

Code is currently as follows:

```
function createCalendarEvent(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var calendar =CalendarApp.getCalendarById('e3pbfcblhsmehusmotijp1r9e8@group.calendar.google.com');

  var startRow =2; //2 exempts header row check if applicable
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow(); //number of rows to process
  var numColumns = sheet.getLastColumn();

  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow,1,numRows-1,numColumns);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  var complete="Done"

  for(var i=0;i<data.length;++i)
    var row = data[i];
    var DONumber = row[1]; //D.O#
    var Address = row[2];  //AddressDe
    var contact = row[3]; //Deliver to Contact
    var phone = row[4];  //Contact Phone Number
    var time = row[5]; //Delivery time
    var instructions = row[6]; //Instructions
    var assign = row[7]; //Which truck to assign to
    var notify = row[8]; //email to notify when delivery is complete
    var goods = row[9]; //Description of goods
    var quantity = row[10]; //Quantiy of each item
    var date = new Date(row[11]);  //Delivery date
    var edate = new Date(row[12]); //end date
    var eventID = row[13]; //stops duplication

if (eventID != complete) {
  var currentCell = sheet.getRange(startRow +i, numColumns);
  calendar.createEvent(contact,date,edate,{
    description: contact + '\r' + phone + '\r' + instructions + '\r' + goods + '\r' + quantity  
  });

  currentCell.setValue(complete);
}
  }
```

[Spreadsheet sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhPHI.png)

Comment: Did your issue get solved?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly:

- You have several rows of data and want to create a Calendar event for each row.
- You want to avoid creating events for rows whose `D.O#` corresponds to an event that has already been created.

If that's the case, then you could use an array to keep track of all the `D.O#` which have got their events created. The idea would be to add the `D.O#` to the array via [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) and, for every iteration, check if the current `D.O#` is in the array (using [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)).

It could be something on the following lines (see inline comments to get details of what the code is doing in the critical lines):

```js
function createCalendarEvent() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('e3pbfcblhsmehusmotijp1r9e8@group.calendar.google.com');
  var startRow = 2;
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();
  var numColumns = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows - 1, numColumns);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var complete = "Done";
  var sentIDs = []; // Array to track D.O that have been sent
  for (var i=0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var DONumber = row[1];   
    var eventID = row[13];
    if (eventID == complete) { // If event was created in a previous script execution, 
      sentIDs.push(DONumber);  // add D.O. to array to avoid same D.O. being sent
    }
    if (sentIDs.indexOf(DONumber) == -1) {
      sentIDs.push(DONumber); // Add to array to avoid same D.O. being sent
      var Address = row[2];
      var contact = row[3]; 
      var phone = row[4];
      var time = row[5];
      var instructions = row[6];
      var assign = row[7];
      var notify = row[8];
      var goods = row[9];
      var quantity = row[10];
      var date = new Date(row[11]);
      var edate = new Date(row[12]);
      var currentCell = sheet.getRange(startRow + i, numColumns);
      calendar.createEvent(contact, date, edate, {
        description: contact + '\r' + phone + '\r' + instructions + '\r' + goods + '\r' + quantity  
      });    
      currentCell.setValue(complete);      
    }
  }
}
```

One thing to highlight is that `eventID` is being used to add the corresponding `D.O.` to the `sentIDs` array to avoid events being created that share the same `D.O.` with an event that was created in a previous execution of the code (see inline comments).

Note: In the sample you provided, opening brackets for the `for` loop are missing. This can cause your code not to work properly. I fixed it in the sample I provide here.

I hope this is of any help.